# Is there more beautiful database drawing software than visio?

Tags: database, drawing, diagramming

I want to know if you know other beautiful database drawing software other than visio.

Because i think visio is not delegant enough. So Can you give me some advice?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Visio's quite extensible, so it can delegate a lot of functionality to scripts and plugins. ( 'delegant'= one who delegates )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know Visio, but I have been using [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) for almost 10 years, and it's great. It's also free (as in speech).

Some people have compared Dia favorably to Visio.

Comment: I Usedom Dia until it screwd up my drawings After/while saving. Too Risk for me, i don't use it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try [www.magicdraw.com](http://www.magicdraw.com).
It produces beautiful diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Designer is the best i have ever used. however, it does not come cheap...

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has built in functions to create graphs.

Saves you from creating a graph first and than the db schema.

Answer (score 1):

[MySql](http://wb.mysql.com/) Workbench is a nice Designer and free. The only drawback I find is that it only produce scripts for mysql.